# Vuforia and ARKit in the same project (different scenes) - is it possible?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia, arkit

Is it possible to include Vuforia and ARKit into the same iOS build in Unity?

So I have a Vuforia Scene and ARKit scene, and I want to switch between the scenes. Is it possible?

Because so far it seems that Vudoria overrides something, and even if I build only the ARKit scene, but Vuforia support is turned on in the player settings - I see vuforia screen instead of ARKit onmy iPhone.

Comment: It's working for me…

Comment: Hey, any solution ?